# Sending emails from CakePHP application using Gmail

Tags: php, email, cakephp, gmail

I'm trying to get the website I'm developing to send password reminder emails. I had the idea of using my Gmail account just to test. From the Cake cookbook, I've got this code:

```
$this->Email->from = 'support@site.com';
$this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
    'port'=>'465',
    'timeout'=>'30',
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'username'=>'notmyrealemail@gmail.com',
    'password'=>'notmyrealpassword');
$this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
$this->Email->from = 'support@imgstore.in';
$this->Email->to = $this->request->data['User']['email'];
$this->Email->subject = 'Your account reset request';
$this->Email->send('testing');
$this->Email->send();
debug($this->Email->smtpError);
```

However, when this code ges executed I'm geting this error:

```
Error: Call to a member function messageID() on a non-object    
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lib\Cake\Controller\Component\EmailComponent.php 
Line: 312

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\fatal_error.ctp
```

What am I doing wrong here? At the moment I just want to test if my application can email properly. However, would Gmail be a decent way of sending emails to my users in production?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use the local sendmail? :)

Comment: Better use the new CakeEmail class, instead of the component. The error would be caused by not having set a subject before calling send() although your code shows you did set it. Is this the actual code causing this fatal? Also you are calling send() twice.

Answer (score 0):

What it seems to be is You did not include the component class into your controller. Include the `EmailComponent` into your controller file.

```
public $components = array('Email');
```

Comment: I do have the email component included in my conroller.